# Column color based when plotting a GeoDataFrame with 'explore' method

Tags: python, geopandas, color, folium

I'd like to **color** the cities that belong to one **hemisphere** or another with the color specified at 'Color' **column**. All the cities of each hemisphere (each category) have the same value for that column. I'd like the legend to show the same colors too.

I'm not being able of getting it. Could anyone help me?

Note: This is a reproducible example of what I'm dealing with -based on geopandas examples.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
gdf['Hemisphere'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: 'Norte'if x.y > 0 else 'Sur')
gdf['Color'] = gdf['Hemisphere'].apply(lambda x: '#D94325' if x=='Norte' else '#5CD925')

gdf.explore(column='Hemisferio', color='Color')
```

[image]

Also available at:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/71128054/13151511

Comment: Please don't post on multiple SE's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cmap argument rather than color - an example using naturalearth lowres dataset

```py
gdf =gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf['color'] = gdf.index.map(lambda x : 'red' if x%2 == 0 else 'blue')
gdf.explore(column='color', cmap=['red', 'blue'], legend=True)
```

[image]